# pandas get delta from corresponding date in a seperate list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
df a b
   7 2019-05-01 00:00:01
   6 2019-05-02 00:15:01 
   1 2019-05-06 00:10:01
   3 2019-05-09 01:00:01
   8 2019-05-09 04:20:01
   9 2019-05-12 01:10:01
   4 2019-05-16 03:30:01
```

And

> `l = [datetime.datetime(2019,05,02), datetime.datetime(2019,05,10), datetime.datetime(2019,05,22) ]`

I want to add a column with the following:
for each row, find the last date from l that is before it, and add number of days between them.
If none of the date is smaller - add the delta from the smallest one.
So the new column will be:

```
df a b.                 delta            date
   7 2019-05-01 00:00:01 -1     datetime.datetime(2019,05,02)
   6 2019-05-02 00:15:01  0     datetime.datetime(2019,05,02)
   1 2019-05-06 00:10:01  4     datetime.datetime(2019,05,02)
   3 2019-05-09 01:00:01  7     datetime.datetime(2019,05,02)
   8 2019-05-09 04:20:01  7     datetime.datetime(2019,05,02)
   9 2019-05-12 01:10:01  2     datetime.datetime(2019,05,10)
   4 2019-05-16 03:30:01  6     datetime.datetime(2019,05,10)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The col 'b' has datetime object and not str right?

Comment: @ArrowRise it is actually has dtype: object but I guess can be transformers with pd.to_datetime()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to align `df['b']` and the list (as Series), then computing the difference:

```
# ensure datetime
df['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df['b'])

# craft Series for merging (could be combined with line below)
s = pd.Series(l, name='l')

# merge and fillna with minimum date
ref = pd.merge_asof(df['b'], s, left_on='b', right_on='l')['l'].fillna(s.min())

# compute the delta as days
df['delta'] =(df['b']-ref).dt.days
```

output:

```
   a                   b  delta
0  7 2019-05-01 00:00:01     -1
1  6 2019-05-02 00:15:01      0
2  1 2019-05-06 00:10:01      4
3  3 2019-05-09 01:00:01      7
4  8 2019-05-09 04:20:01      7
5  9 2019-05-12 01:10:01      2
6  4 2019-05-16 03:30:01      6
```

Comment: How can I add also the last date taken from l, as an additional column? (Please see edit)

Comment: This is the series in `ref` (before `fillna` if you want to keep NaN on no match)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one line solution if you your `b` column has `datetime` object. Otherwise convert it to `datetime` object.

```
df['delta'] = df.apply(lambda x: sorted([x.b - i for i in l], key= lambda y: y.seconds)[0].days, axis=1)
```

Explanation : To each row you apply a function that :

- Compute the `deltatime` between your row's `datetime` and every `datetime` present in `l`, then store it in a list
- Sort this list by the numbers of seconds of each `deltatime`
- Get the first value (with the smallest `deltatime`) and return its `days`

Answer (score 0):

this code is seperate this dataset on

- weekday     **Friday**
- year        **2014**
- day          **01**
- hour         **00**
- minute       **03**

```py
rides['weekday'] = rides.timestamp.dt.strftime("%A")
rides['year'] = rides.timestamp.dt.strftime("%Y")
rides['day'] = rides.timestamp.dt.strftime("%d")
rides['hour'] = rides.timestamp.dt.strftime("%H")
rides["minute"] = rides.timestamp.dt.strftime("%M")
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question